# Regex- GetGroupNames returning more groups than expected

Tags: c#, regex

I cant understand what is going on with my regex's.
I have a below pseudo-code:

```
string patternRegex="^(?<GROUP_1>[1-4][0-9]|7[3-9]|8[0-9])(?<GROUP_2>(\\d{5}))$"
Regex regex = new Regex(patternRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled);
var groupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();
```

I expect that `GetGroupNames()` should return me two groups (`GROUP_1` and `GROUP_2`), but in this case it returns me 4 groups.

1. 0
2. 1
3. GROUP_1
4. GROUP_2

When i try to match string: `1395614`, the group values are:

1. 1395614
2. 95614
3. 13
4. 95614

I already googled it, and i read somewhere that `0` group stands for the full match.

`GROUP_1` and `GROUP_2` values are also correct.

But what group `1` (im not asking here about `GROUP_1`) stands for?

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bfgv9s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid default unnamed capturing group with index 1, you should rewrite your regexp to

`string patternRegex = "^(?<GROUP_1>(?:[1-4][0-9]|7[3-9]|8[0-9]))(?<GROUP_2>(?:\\d{5}))$";`

For the first capturing group `GROUP_1`, use `(?:[1-4][0-9]|7[3-9]|8[0-9])` instead of `[1-4][0-9]|7[3-9]|8[0-9]`.
The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that allows us to group parts of the pattern without creating a capturing group. It ensures that the match for this part will not be assigned to a capturing group.

For the second capturing group `GROUP_2`, use `(?:\\d{5})` instead of `\\d{5}`.
Again, `(?:\\d{5})` is a non-capturing group.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for sharing non-capturing groups syntax

Comment: Thank you, that's a complete solution and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you have the full match.
You have also a group for each parenthesis couple.

Basically you have also this match : (\d{5}) which is captured as group "1"

You can access the captured groups this way:

```
var match = regex.Match("1395614");
var group1 = match.Groups["GROUP_1"].Value;
```

To prevent group from being catched, simply add `?:` that stands for `non capturing group`  to the `(\d{5})` group.

It should look like: `(?:\d{5})`.

Comment: And what is the reason/logic behind that, or any ideas how to avoid it ?

Comment: The logic is that c# creates a group for each parenthesis couple. If the group is not named, which is the case here, c# labels automatically the group

Comment: it wasnt me who downvoted this, your answer is correct. thank you! However, to prevent that group from being catched, i found out its just enough to add `?:` to the `(\d{5})` group. `?:` stands for `non capturing group`

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik I don't have enough reputation to know who this is, I wasn't implying this was you, thanks for the vote. Yaroslavm answer is quite useful for your case I think